# Lines in a django's template

Tags: css, django, templates

In django, I have a line

```
                    <th class="indigo">
                        <a href="{{ req_url }}?state__iexact=validation" data-turbolinks="false">
                            <b v-text="dashboard.requests.state.daily.validation">0</b> {% trans "Notice 7 days" %}
                        </a>
                    </th>
```

which gave me the following image

[image]

I would like move the number `0` bellow `Notice 7 days` and increase the size of the writting. Could anyone be able to tell me how could I proceed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would add the css tag, since this question is pure about styling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
<th class="indigo">
    <a href="{{ req_url }}?state__iexact=validation" data-turbolinks="false">
        {% trans "Notice 7 days" %}
        <br> <!-- This is a new line -->
        <b v-text="dashboard.requests.state.daily.validation">0</b>
    </a>
</th>
```

To increase the size, you can add some css, for example:

```
<style>
    .indigo {
        font-size:17px;
    }
</style>
```